# How do the arc and the straight line have equal length in this figure?

Tags: antennas, radio-frequency

I have the following derivation in one of my physics problem related to range of a transmitting antenna:

[image]

How is the distance QT equal to the length of arc PT? Can someone provide a quick explanation or proof of somekind?

Comment: The key is in $h_T\ll R$. Your drawing is not at scale. If the height of the antenna is much less than the radius of the Earth (which seems reasonable), then the arc length approximately equals the Euclidean distance $PT$. Look about the point where the book says "therefore".

Comment: I agree with the answers, but the way it is presented in the book is extremely misleading. They leverage $R >> h_T$ before they mention that they use this fact, and present $QT=d$ as if this was always exactly true and not just an approximation.

Comment: Yes, they should have probably used the $ \approx $ symbol somewhere, to make it clearer.

Comment: @noah yes I was just thinking about that. I thought QT = d was a fact and I couldn't wrap my head around that. Thank You. Thank You for the explanation.

Comment: @joigus Thank You

Answer (score 0):

In reality, they are not equal. However, QT is at least as long as the arc PT, and the most QT could be is the length of the arc plus the height of the tower:

$PT < QT < PT + h_T$

But since the height of the tower is at most tens of meters, and the distance of PT likely in kilometers, $PT \approx PT + h_T$.

And thus, for all intents and purposes, $PT \approx QT$.